# include property from derived class EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

case: i have a list of Companies, each Company contains one Store and some other properties like address, name, .... A store can be of type FruitStore or of type VegetableStore (both are derived from Store).  If the store is a fruitstore i want to include a property that is unique for fruitstore for example TheBestOrange (wich is an object).

how do i include theBestOrange in my query and also the properties from company?

I have

```
companies.Include(s => s.Store)
         .OfType<FruitStore>()
         .Include(a => a.theBestOrange)
```

but this changes my return type to a list of fruitstores instead of a list of companies

i hope i made myself clear.

Comment: The `OfType<T>()` LINQ method filters you enumerable to those only of the provided type.

Comment: and is there another solution so it does not filter to the provided type bu enables me to include properties of this type?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with EF, I'd say no. You could try and do 2 queries which you jam together with Zip(vegetableStores,fruitStores) before forcing execution with ToList() or something. Given EF's defered execution that could work and only cost you one trip to the database.

Comment: the `.select( )` method. This blog from Jon Skeet may help http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to include all stores in your query, not just fruit stores. You can't project to a list of objects where some of the objects include a property and others don't, since they would be different types. So it will have to be a nullable property. Maybe something like this (untested):

```
var query = companies.Select(c => new { 
    CompanyProp1 = c.CompanyProp1, 
    CompanyProp2 = c.CompanyProp2, 
    StoreProp1 = c.Store.StoreProp1,
    TheBestOrange = c.Store is FruitStore ? ((FruitStore)c.Store).theBestOrange : null
});
```